# MySQL Connector/ODBC: Connection failed: Can't open named pipe

Tags: mysql, windows, odbc

Today a Microsoft Windows machine was unable to use the official MySQL client called "[MySQL Connector/ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/)" to connect to a different MySQL server on a GNU/Linux machine, in the same LAN, via TCP/IP, standard port `3306`, listening on all interfaces and without firewalls.

The connection from the Microsoft Windows client failed with this error message:

> Connection Failed
> [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver] Can't open named pipe to host: xxx pipe: Mysql (s):
> [image: MySQL Connector ODBC Can't open named pipe]

### Notes

- there is no firewall in the LAN
- the port is worldwide opened
- the credentials are OK

### Question

Since this error message is nonsense... what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in the MySQL connector, at least version `8.0`.

The client is ignoring your check on the `TCP/IP` option and it's using a legacy connection method called `Named Pipe` that it's not supported by your server (and should not - to be honest).

To make sure that the client does not use the `Named Pipe` method, select it, empty the text field (the one that in the example contains the text "`Mysql`"), and select again `TCP/IP`.

Now it will work!

It would be nice to discover if it exists an upstream bug in MySQL for that.